# Label background color depending on expression in QGIS print layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a problem with the background color in a label in print layout in QGIS.
I would like to set the color of the label to be dependent on the data from the attribute table.

For example, when column A=1 the background will be yellow. When column A=1, green etc.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

You can set an expression to control the colour of the "halo" of your text label.

[image]

Once you've clicked that button chose `edit` and then you can add any expression you like, something like this should work:

```
CASE 
  WHEN   "objectid" = 1 THEN color_rgb( 0,0,0) 
  WHEN   "objectid" = 2 THEN color_rgb( 10,0,0)
 END
```

Comment: If you want to match the background color to the symbol color you could use @symbol_color expression

Comment: I think the OP wants a different colour to the background, otherwise why bother with a halo

Comment: Ok, but it's about label in print layout (in text field).
When I add a text fiel, I would like the background color to change depending on the attribute table.

In option "background" there is not choince "extension".

Comment: I'm not sure if that could work, the text field doesn't know which feature you want to consider.